# python match email id with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the email id with  regular expression, in the following what am i doing wrong,

```
 mail="something@redddf.com"
 >>> re.findall(r"\w+@.*",mail)
 ['something@redddf.com']


 >>> re.findall(r"\w+@\.\(com|in\)",mail)
 []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues

1. You don't escape parenthesis when using python regex
2. You didn't include the domain name match

Here is how it should be

```
>>> re.findall(r"\w+@\w+\.(?:com|in)",mail)
['something@redddf.com']
>>>
```

Comment: These are valid email addresses: `m.a@i.l.com` `m+b@d-d.com.com` for example. It's really not just a word@word.com

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with [some dedicated sites](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for this task.